# Get a command output in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a shell script that automatically kills the process that is running in a given port, on a Ubuntu 14.10 dedicated server.

As far as I know, using `fuser -n tcp {port-number}` gives the PID of the process running in that port, example: http://prntscr.com/81whib

Also, I know that `kill -9 {PID}` kills the process with such PID.

How could I make a shell script that gets the output of the command `fuser -n tcp {port-number}` and uses it in the command `kill -9 {PID}` ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `fuser -k -n tcp <port-number> -k` (or preferably, `fuser -TERM -n tcp <port-number>` to kill the process using the port instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the output of `fuser` using [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) (sample using port 139):

```
pid=$(fuser -n tcp 139 | awk '{print $1}')
echo $pid
# kill -9 $pid , etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will allow you to pass in a port (e.g. `./killProcess 25565`) and will kill the process so long as a PID exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(fuser -n tcp $1 | awk '{print $2}')

if [ ! -z "$PID" ]; then
    kill -9 $PID
else
    echo "No process is running on port $1"
fi
```

Comment: the second group  (from `{print $2}`) was giving me the empty string... is it working for you?

Comment: @ChrisSprague Yes, this is working on my machine. Added an else  statement that will execute if no process (PID) was found for the given port.